# After update on Google play - status of local json file

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application on Google play and I'm going to release new update. I use some resourch data like json files. I made some important changes and non of them effect json file structure. I create json file on runtime.
My file locatin is : `/data/data/com.example/app_updatedir"+"/update.json`

What will happen after the new update file status? Notchange, update or recreate?